# disable srcset for specific page template

Tags: wordpress, responsive, srcset

I'm trying to disable reponsive images in Wordpress for specific page templates (which are being used for custom RSS feed where srcset is not appropriate).

```
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', '__return_false' );
```

in the functions.php of th theme does the job for all images everywhere.

But as soon as I use a conditional tag, it stops working entirely, like:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-mytemplate.php' ) ) {
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', '__return_false' );
}
```

Any ideas how to get it to work?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what your doing but why not just edit the template file to remove/replace the function adding srcset ?

Comment: The srcset is coming from the Wordpress core, so the code generating it is not in the template. In Wordpress you add the content of a post with a function that covers the whole content part ...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying do the same. To turn off srcset on shop catalog product thumbnails only but it turns off on all pages.

(I have increase scale image effect on thumb hover and it hovering low quality srcset)

```
function m_disable_srcset( $size ) {
if ( $size = 'shop_catalog' ) {
return false;
}}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'm_disable_srcset' );
```

EDIT: this code worked:

```
/**
 * Remove the srcset attribute from post thumbnails 
 * that are called with the 'full' size string: the_post_thumbnail( 'full' )
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214071/26350
 */
 add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_size', function( $size )
 {
     if( is_string( $size ) && 'shop_catalog' === $size )
         add_filter( 
             'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta',  
              '__return_null_and_remove_current_filter' 
         );   
    return $size;
 } );

// Would be handy, in this example, to have this as a core function ;-)
function __return_null_and_remove_current_filter ( $var )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using jQuery. It helped me.

```
jQuery( "img" ).removeAttr('srcset');
```